# Divide a frame into 3 sections in latex beamer

Tags: beamer

I need the frame of LaTeX beamer to be divided into three sections as shown. With contents of sections 2 and 3 changing with each item of section 1.How do I do that?

[image: framesectioning]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Please help us to help you and add a *full* minimal working example [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. Is easier for us in this way can help you copiyng and running code instead watch a screenshot.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a combination of `multicols` and `minipage`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{multicol}

\begin{document}

\section{Section 1}
\begin{frame}{Frame 1}
  \begin{multicols}{2}
    \begin{minipage}[b][20ex][t]{\linewidth}
      Section 1
      \begin{itemize}
        \item<1-> Item 1
        \item<2-> Item 2
        \item<3-> Item 3
      \end{itemize}
    \end{minipage}

    \begin{minipage}[b][20ex][t]{\linewidth}
      Section 2

      \only<1>{
        Content 1 in section 2
      }
      \only<2>{
        Content 2 in section 2
      }
      \only<3>{
        Content 3 in section 2
      }
    \end{minipage}

    \begin{minipage}[b][40ex][t]{\linewidth}
      Section 3

      \only<1>{
        Content 1 in section 3
      }
      \only<2>{
        Content 2 in section 3
      }
      \only<3>{
        Content 3 in section 3
      }
    \end{minipage}
  \end{multicols}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a (creative) way to separate 4 minipages with lines in a slide.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{default}
\usepackage{rotating}

\newcommand\FourQuad[4]{%
 \begin{minipage}[b][.33\textheight][t] 
  {.48\textwidth}#1\end{minipage}\hfill%
 \begin{minipage}[b][.33\textheight][t] 
  {.48\textwidth}#2\end{minipage}\\[0.5em]
 \begin{minipage}[b][.33\textheight][t] 
  {.48\textwidth}#3\end{minipage}\hfill
 \begin{minipage}[b][.33\textheight][t] 
  {.48\textwidth}#4\end{minipage}%
 }

\begin{document}
 \begin{frame}{4 quadrants with Beamer}
  \FourQuad%
   { \begin{itemize}
      \item<1-> Item 1
     \end{itemize}\vspace{2cm}\hspace{2.7cm}
     \makebox[\linewidth]{\resizebox{2.9\linewidth}{1pt}{$\bullet$}}
   }
   { \begin{itemize}
      \item<1-> Item 2
     \end{itemize}\vspace{2cm} 
   }
   { \begin{itemize}
      \item<1-> Item 3
     \end{itemize} 
   }
   { \begin{itemize}
      \item<1-> Item 4
     \end{itemize}\vspace{1.5cm}
     \begin{rotate}{90}\makebox[\linewidth]{\resizebox{2.0\linewidth} 
     {1pt}{$\bullet$}}\end{rotate}
   }

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Stay creative :)